# How to install wipefs in Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management

I ran `apt-cache search wipefs` and `aptitude search wipefs` unsuccessfully.

How can I install `wipefs` in Ubuntu?

Comment: `apt-cache` is a good idea if you now the package name. But in your case `apt-file search wipefs` is the better choice.

Comment: @A.B. Make that an answer because I think it is the best one here because I did not know `apt-file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-cache` is a good idea if you now the package name. But in your case `apt-file search wipefs` is the better choice.

```
% apt-file search wipefs
manpages-de: /usr/share/man/de/man8/wipefs.8.gz
manpages-fr-extra: /usr/share/man/fr/man8/wipefs.8.gz
util-linux: /sbin/wipefs
util-linux: /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/wipefs
util-linux: /usr/share/man/man8/wipefs.8.gz
```

We know, that we search the binary, usually located in `/bin`, `/usr/bin` or `/sbin`, therefore your package name is `util-linux` and you can install it, as @Rinzwind said with

```
sudo apt-get install util-linux
```

---

To use `apt_file` you have to install it

```
sudo apt-get install apt_file
```

and refresh the database

```
apt-file update
```

---

Other examples for `apt-file`

```
% apt-file search --regex "/wipefs$"
util-linux: /sbin/wipefs
util-linux: /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/wipefs
```

or if `wipefs` is already installed and you need the package name

```
% apt-file search  "$(which wipefs)"
util-linux: /sbin/wipefs
```

---

More tools

- `dpkg`

  ```
  % dpkg -S wipefs   
  util-linux: /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/wipefs
  util-linux: /usr/share/man/man8/wipefs.8.gz
  util-linux: /sbin/wipefs
  ```
- `auto-apt`

  ```
  sudo apt-get install auto-apt
  sudo auto-apt update
  auto-apt search wipefs
  ```

Comment: I had to add to PATH `/sbin/` to have it there too.

Answer (score 2):

[See the man page for wipefs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/wipefs.8.html).

It is part of [util-linux(-ng)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux) and already installed in the base system.

```
$ which wipefs
/sbin/wipefs

$ wipefs --version
wipefs from util-linux 2.25.2
```

From Ubuntu Software Center:

[image: Ubuntu Software Center - util-linux]

So the command would be:

```
sudo apt-get install util-linux
```

but normally this would show an error message stating it is already installed.